# Python to influxdb - insert if no record

Tags: python, influxdb, influxdb-python

I know influx is for measurement type data.  But I'm also using it for annotations on certain events.

I have scripts that run every minute, that it would be difficult for it to realise an event has already happened.  Is there something I can do on the insert to only insert if a new record rather than every time.

Comment: Looking for this too. Something like MySQL's `INSERT IGNORE` would be of great use...

Answer (score 0):

So there didn't seem to be a way of doing it (and no answers here).  But I solved the problem by performing a query first and if no record found perform an insert.

Basically i had to make the scripts figure it out.